# How sql convert one row from datatable to xml?

Tags: xml, oracle

How convert one row from datatable to xml?

I have a select - for example:

```
select
    '0000' bank_code
    ,'0'   confirm_code
    ,'success' confirm_message
    ,sysdate trtime_trdatetime
    ,'123456789' sender_acc
    ,'aaaaaa' sender_name
    ,'123456789' reciver_acc
    ,'aaaaaa' reciver_name
    ,150 amount_value
    ,'' dsignature
from 
    dual
```

I need convert its results to this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <sendfund xmlns="http://blabla.com/">
      <bank>
        <code>string</code>
      </bank>
      <transaction>
        <confirm>
          <code>string</code>
          <message>string</message>
        </confirm>
        <trtime>
          <trdatetime> </trdatetime>
        </trtime>
        <sender>
          <acc>string</acc>
          <name>string</name>
        </sender>
        <reciver>
          <acc>string</acc>
          <name>string</name>
        </reciver>
        <amount>
          <value>1500</value>
        </amount>
        <dsignature> </dsignature>
     </transaction>
    </sendfund>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do it? I'm reading convert on fly with xmltransform but how use it I can't or which function use it for custom xml?

Comment: did you try `select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('your query') xdoc from dual` ??

Comment: Yes but not I want result

Comment: dbms_xmlgen converts a query result to xml

Comment: `select dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
'select' || chr(10) ||
'''0000'' bank_code' || chr(10) ||
',''0''   confirm_code' || chr(10) ||
',''success'' confirm_message' || chr(10) ||
',sysdate trtime_trdatetime' || chr(10) ||
',''123456789'' sender_acc' || chr(10) ||
',''aaaaaa'' sender_name' || chr(10) ||
',''123456789'' reciver_acc' || chr(10) ||
',''aaaaaa'' reciver_name' || chr(10) ||
',150 amount_value' || chr(10) ||
','''' dsignature' || chr(10) ||
'from dual') xdoc from dual`

I need custom fixed XML template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't registered own xml schema, the easiest way is to use xmlquery with variables:

```sql
select
xmlquery(
      'declare namespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; 
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <sendfund xmlns="http://blabla.com/">
      <bank>
        <code>{$bank_code}</code>
      </bank>
      <transaction>
        <confirm>
          <code>{$confirm_code}</code>
          <message>{$confirm_message}</message>
        </confirm>
        <trtime>
          <trdatetime>{$trtime_trdatetime} </trdatetime>
        </trtime>
        <sender>
          <acc>{$sender_acc}</acc>
          <name>{$sender_name}</name>
        </sender>
        <reciver>
          <acc>{$reciver_acc}</acc>
          <name>{$reciver_name}</name>
        </reciver>
        <amount>
          <value>{$amount_value}</value>
        </amount>
        <dsignature>{$dsignature}</dsignature>
     </transaction>
    </sendfund>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
      '
      passing         
      bank_code          as "bank_code", 
      confirm_code       as "confirm_code", 
      confirm_message    as "confirm_message", 
      trtime_trdatetime  as "trtime_trdatetime", 
      sender_acc         as "sender_acc", 
      sender_name        as "sender_name", 
      reciver_acc        as "reciver_acc", 
      reciver_name       as "reciver_name", 
      amount_value       as "amount_value", 
      dsignature         as "dsignature"
      returning content
   ) as xdata
from 
   (
    select 
       '0000'        bank_code
       ,'0'          confirm_code
       ,'success'    confirm_message
       ,sysdate      trtime_trdatetime
       ,'123456789'  sender_acc
       ,'aaaaaa'     sender_name
       ,'123456789'  reciver_acc
       ,'aaaaaa'     reciver_name
       ,150          amount_value
       ,''           dsignature
    from dual
    ) t;
```

Another a bit more difficult, but more correct way to generate such documents is to use special functions like xmlroot,xmlelement,xmlforest:

```sql
select
   xmlroot(
      xmlelement(
         "soap:Envelope"
        ,XMLATTRIBUTES('http://blabla.com/' as "xmlns:soap")
        ,xmlelement(
           "soap:Body"
          ,xmlelement(
             "sendfunc"
            ,XMLATTRIBUTES('http://blabla.com/' as "xmlns")
            ,xmlforest(
                xmlelement("code", bank_code) as "bank"
               ,xmlforest(
                    xmlforest(
                       confirm_code as "code",
                       confirm_message as "message"
                    ) as "confirm"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       trtime_trdatetime as "trdatetime"
                    ) as "trtime"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       sender_acc as "acc",
                       sender_name as "name"
                    ) as "sender"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       reciver_acc as "acc",
                       reciver_name as "name"
                    ) as "reciver"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       amount_value as "value"
                    ) as "amount"
                   ,dsignature as "dsignature"
               ) as "transaction"
            )
           )
         )
      )
    , VERSION '1.0'
   ) xdata
from(
  select
    '0000' bank_code
    ,'0'   confirm_code
    ,'success' confirm_message
    ,sysdate trtime_trdatetime
    ,'123456789' sender_acc
    ,'aaaaaa' sender_name
    ,'123456789' reciver_acc
    ,'aaaaaa' reciver_name
    ,150 amount_value
    ,'' dsignature
    from dual
    );
```

Update: if you need to export it in exact encoding you need to use xmlserialize function, ie just pass ready xmltype from examples above to xmlserialize:
for example, xmlquery:

```sql
select 
   xmlserialize(document xdata as blob encoding 'UTF-8' version '1.0') x_serialized
from (
  select 
     xmlquery(
      'declare namespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; 
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <sendfund xmlns="http://blabla.com/">
      <bank>
        <code>{$bank_code}</code>
      </bank>
      <transaction>
        <confirm>
          <code>{$confirm_code}</code>
          <message>{$confirm_message}</message>
        </confirm>
        <trtime>
          <trdatetime>{$trtime_trdatetime} </trdatetime>
        </trtime>
        <sender>
          <acc>{$sender_acc}</acc>
          <name>{$sender_name}</name>
        </sender>
        <reciver>
          <acc>{$reciver_acc}</acc>
          <name>{$reciver_name}</name>
        </reciver>
        <amount>
          <value>{$amount_value}</value>
        </amount>
        <dsignature>{$dsignature}</dsignature>
     </transaction>
    </sendfund>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
      '
      passing         
      bank_code          as "bank_code", 
      confirm_code       as "confirm_code", 
      confirm_message    as "confirm_message", 
      trtime_trdatetime  as "trtime_trdatetime", 
      sender_acc         as "sender_acc", 
      sender_name        as "sender_name", 
      reciver_acc        as "reciver_acc", 
      reciver_name       as "reciver_name", 
      amount_value       as "amount_value", 
      dsignature         as "dsignature"
      returning content
   ) as xdata
from 
   (
    select 
       '0000'        bank_code
       ,'0'          confirm_code
       ,'success'    confirm_message
       ,sysdate      trtime_trdatetime
       ,'123456789'  sender_acc
       ,'aaaaaa'     sender_name
       ,'123456789'  reciver_acc
       ,'aaaaaa'     reciver_name
       ,150          amount_value
       ,''           dsignature
    from dual
    ) t
);
```

XMLROOT/XMLELEMENT/XMLFOREST:

```sql
select 
   xmlserialize(document xdata as blob encoding 'UTF-8' version '1.0' indent size=2) x_serialized
from (
select
   xmlroot(
      xmlelement(
         "soap:Envelope"
        ,XMLATTRIBUTES('http://blabla.com/' as "xmlns:soap")
        ,xmlelement(
           "soap:Body"
          ,xmlelement(
             "sendfunc"
            ,XMLATTRIBUTES('http://blabla.com/' as "xmlns")
            ,xmlforest(
                xmlelement("code", bank_code) as "bank"
               ,xmlforest(
                    xmlforest(
                       confirm_code as "code",
                       confirm_message as "message"
                    ) as "confirm"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       trtime_trdatetime as "trdatetime"
                    ) as "trtime"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       sender_acc as "acc",
                       sender_name as "name"
                    ) as "sender"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       reciver_acc as "acc",
                       reciver_name as "name"
                    ) as "reciver"
                   ,xmlforest(
                       amount_value as "value"
                    ) as "amount"
                   ,dsignature as "dsignature"
               ) as "transaction"
            )
           )
         )
      )
    , VERSION '1.0'
   ) xdata
from(
  select
    '0000' bank_code
    ,'0'   confirm_code
    ,'success' confirm_message
    ,sysdate trtime_trdatetime
    ,'123456789' sender_acc
    ,'aaaaaa' sender_name
    ,'123456789' reciver_acc
    ,'aaaaaa' reciver_name
    ,150 amount_value
    ,'' dsignature
    from dual
    )
);
```

Comment: big 10x
how add this line 
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: @GoodBit encoding is a special parameter for text exporting, if you want to export xmltype as a text you need to wrap returning xmltype into xmlserialize function. One minute, I'll update my answer with it too

Comment: @GoodBit I've updated the answer with xmlserialize into required encoding

Comment: just little question how format xml like this?
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://blabla.com/">
 <soap:Body>
  <sendfunc xmlns="http://blabla.com/">
   <bank>
    <code>0000</code>
   </bank>
   <transaction>
    <confirm>
     <code>0</code>
     <message>success</message>
    </confirm>`

Comment: Have you checked my last example above?

Comment: yes but return not pretty formatted without INDENT.. How use it INDENT?
I mean xdata INDENT SIZE = 2

Comment: @GoodBit mr.Ulugbek? :) Just replace `xmlserialize(...)` to `xmlserialize(document xdata as blob encoding 'UTF-8' version '1.0' indent size=2) x_serialized`

Comment: Yes 2 front side :) but unfornutanly without indent may be plsql developer work like this
Okay 10x anyway for helping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221447/discussion-between-sayan-malakshinov-and-good-bit).